# Brew Update not working after mac 10.9

Tags: homebrew

First time running brew since 10.9 upgrade.

From the output below, should I just remove Library/Formula/ant.rb and Library/Formula/apple-gcc42.rb? Also, unclear why git pull is failing. Thanks for any help

```
525    [projects]$  brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git
HEAD: 27c26faf7b958de6028ad55be8ccc5a57b094d3f
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.9-x86_64
Xcode: 5.0.2
GCC-4.2: build 5666
LLVM-GCC: build 0
Clang: 5.0 build 500
X11: N/A
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /Users/*****/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby
526    [projects]$  brew update
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Formula/ant.rb
    Library/Formula/apple-gcc42.rb
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull -q origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 193, accepted):

This fixed it for me

```
cd `brew --prefix`/Homebrew
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

brew update worked fine after that

Comment: I had to use ```sudo git reset --hard origin/master``` for the last command.

Comment: after executing above steps. When I did brew update. I had the following error                            You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local

Comment: worked for me after performing a time machine migration

Comment: I found this after I read a instructions by DomT4 that essentially said the same thing. So I marked this as a working answer.   https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/41665

Comment: For some reason, `brew update` had failed to actually update anything for well over a week. This fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Work in December 2022 with my MACBOOK PRO Ventura 13.1. My 'brew update' dont work and worked in the infinity.

Answer (score 11):

### Solution

> You might still find..
>
> brew update **not working** after `git pull origin master`

### Here what you need to do.

`cd /usr/local
git pull origin master
brew install git`

Now you might already have git on your System, 
but what this will do it that now.

Your broken brew update will automatically be updated before at first run..

Here is the link to the origin issue in HomeBrew. [brew stuck](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/19460)

Comment: For me I got to this point and it finally gave me an error about having 2 xcode versions installed. I had an extra for legacy development of a project /facepalm

Answer (score 11):

My brew update was hanging and doing nothing. I am on OSX 10.12.5 and none of the above worked for me and I have no .git in `usr/local`, only in `usr/local/Homebrew`.

I ran `brew update --debug --verbose` and `brew update` and that fixed the issue, see this issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/895

Answer (score 6):

I simply removed the `.git` directory inside of the `/usr/local` directory, then ran the command `brew update`.

Answer (score 1):

I did this to solve the problem

```
cd /usr/local
git pull origin master
```

Comment: missing context

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to update the brew like [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3285):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Answer (score 1):

On Big Sur 11.1 fixed it for me:

`git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow`

Brew self described it as:

> To `brew update`, first run:
> `git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow`
> This restriction has been made on GitHub's request because updating shallow
> clones is an extremely expensive operation due to the tree layout and traffic of
> Homebrew/homebrew-core and Homebrew/homebrew-cask. We don't do this for you
> automatically to avoid repeatedly performing an expensive unshallow operation in
> CI systems (which should instead be fixed to not use shallow clones). Sorry for
> the inconvenience!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all solutions posted here but nothing had worked.
I have found solution to fix the problems retated to Homebrew and that is "brew doctor". This command option diagnose the problem and suggest the solution. For my case, the command showed following comment.

I guess this command would solve many problems related to home brew so try it out!

```
❯ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 13.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me on Big Sur 11.4 was first following Pritam comment by executing the following command:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And then executing the following (what MoD said but with addition):

```
git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow && git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow
```

It took a while for both commands to finish, don't worry it's not you.... just let them run

Comment: Running the first command was enough for me