# 404 error when using brew to install mysql - macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, homebrew, macos-sierra

This question has been asked before here ([404 error when using brew to install mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031002/404-error-when-using-brew-to-install-mysql)), but unfortunately the fix doesn't work for me. I have already ran brew update, so I'm up to date.

I'm on the latest version of MacOS 10.12 and I am running Xcode 8 if that matters.

> brew install mysql
>   Warning: You are using OS X 10.12.
>   We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
>   You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
>   ==> Downloading https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-boost-5.7.11.tar.gz
>
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found Error:
>   Failed to download resource "mysql" Download failed:
>   https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-boost-5.7.11.tar.gz

I know it says this is a pre-release version, but is there any hope here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 5.7.11 mysql download you reference no longer exists (it certainly is 404).

Looking at the [homebrew formula for mysql](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/mysql.rb), it has been updated to point to the latest mysql version.

So it seems that you are not in fact up to date. Try running `brew update` twice, then `brew doctor` and fix any warnings.

There have been some big changes in homebrew over the last 9 months, if you have an old install it might be easier to uninstall totally. There are also several ownership and directory location changes that need to be straightened out with the upgrade to homebrew 1.0

Comment: I ran brew update a few times, it definitely think its up to date. I'll see if removing the warnings will help.

Comment: I'm running into the same issues as @Darye :( `brew update` just returns Already up-to-date and `brew install mysql` returns a 404 :(

Comment: so what fixed it was totally uninstalling homebrew and then reinstalling the latest version.

Comment: @WadeWilliams if you update your answer to your answer in the comments, I can mark it as the answer, since that is what solved it for me

Answer (score 5):

I followed the steps laid out here: [Brew Update not working after mac 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133587/brew-update-not-working-after-mac-10-9)

In case that's not visible anymore, here's that answer:

```
cd `brew --prefix`
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

After that, you should be able to `brew update` and then `brew install mysql`

Comment: thanks, this probably would've taken care of it, but I ended up doing what Wade Williams mentioned and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling to resolve this.

Please try:

```
brew update-reset
brew update
```

I found this gem [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3410#issuecomment-343922422).

P.S.: If you have a shallow clone, after `brew update-reset` command, run the following command to `unshallow`:

`git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow`